# Usage of HSSFChart from Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I need to create a HSSFChart object but I'm struggling in the way how I should create a instace of it.
When I use the standard way (HSSFChart chart = new HSSFChart();) it's says that the constructor is private and indeed it is.
How can I use it?

Comment: https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFChart.html

Comment: `HSSFChart` is completely unready up to now. And I doubt it will get ready at all. The usage of the old binary `*.xls` file format decreases over the time in favorit of the new OOXML `*.xlsx` file format. So who cares about it in, lets say, 5 years? And that will be the development period for this at least. So Apache POI should better invest time to stay up to date for the currently used file formats. There is enough work to do.